# Polymer custom element styles with HTML imports

Tags: css, polymer

I have a custom element which is using styles that are being imported via an HTML import.

As of Chrome Stable (35.0.1916.114) and Canary (37.0.2008.2 canary), those styles are no longer being applied to the templates defined inside the custom element. Safari (7.04) and Firefox Aurora [29.0a2 (2014-02-11)] looks good.

Is there a regression in Chrome ?

E.g. my imports.html looks like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/stylesheets/libs/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen">
<script src="/assets/javascripts/libs/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/javascripts/libs/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My polymer element definition looks like:

```
<link rel="import" href="imports.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="x-test">
<template>
  <select id="test">
    <option template repeat="{{ item in items }}" name="{{ item.id }}">
      {{ item.value }}
    </option>
  </select>
</template>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    Polymer('x-test', {
      ... 
    });
  })();
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

Polymer version being used is:

```
"platform": "Polymer/platform#0.2.4",
"core-action-icons": "Polymer/core-action-icons#0.2.4"
"version": "0.2.4"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome 35 is using real ShadowDOM and you're seeing the effects of ShadowDOM style encapsulation. The polyfill version is different is because it doesn't fully support ShadowDOM style scoping.

If you want boostrap styles to apply to elements in side your shadow dom, you need to include the stylesheet inside the polymer-element template. Otherwise, rewrite rules to use `::shadow` and `/deep/`.

More info:

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/#toc-style-disbtributed-nodes
- http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/styling-elements.html
- http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html

Comment: Would you recommend using a single bootstrap import in the host page (via an HTML import) and using `::shadow` and `/deep/` or defining a single custom element whose template brings in the styles, and let the browser de-dupe the network requests for the style sheet (as those styles may get embedded within multiple custom elements?)

Comment: Using a common element to pull in the styles is not a viable solution as the common elements' styles are themselves scoped. So I guess its just easier to include the stylesheet inside every template element that needs them.

Comment: @ebidel the ::shadow and /deep/ are deprecated, what could be the alternate option?

Comment: CSS custom properties: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html

Answer (score 1):

As it's not easier to include the stylesheet in every templete element, so I think a special bootstrap should be provided, adding `/deep/` to it's selectors.

For example, for `breadcrumb`, it should be changed from

```
.breadcrumb {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.breadcrumb > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.breadcrumb > li + li:before {
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: #ccc;
  content: "/\00a0";
}
.breadcrumb > .active {
  color: #999;
}
```

to

```
body /deep/ .breadcrumb {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
body /deep/ .breadcrumb > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
body /deep/ .breadcrumb > li + li:before {
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: #ccc;
  content: "/\00a0";
}
body /deep/ .breadcrumb > .active {
  color: #999;
}
```

It's not easy to do so, or should be easy to do so...

Then, @ebidel, any advice?

Comment: Why isn't it easy to include bootstrap's css in every element that uses it? CSS that makes heavy use of /deep/ breaks the style encapsulation provided by Polymer. It's a bit trickier to get started with, but better overall. Instead I think it would be best to have proper web component implementations of bootstrap's elements.

Comment: In this case, the bootstrap's css will be loaded several times instead of one time. So if all the custom elements should have the same style, it's unnecessary to load the same css for every custom elements. Otherwise, the css should be loaded separately, without the hack `/deep/` which is not supported by bootstrap's `less`. From the design of ShadowDOM, the css shouldn't support style's global scope, however, at that time, I have nothing to test without polymer.

Comment: Including Bootstrap's CSS (in every custom element) works, but violates the DRY principle. Unfortunately, the options seem to be: a) use /deep/ and modify bootstrap's styles or b) include CSS in every element declaration. Not sure, if there is another way to solve this.

Comment: @Rahul, yes, as include css in every element's declaration violates the DRY principle, and even polymer includes a `/deep/` css in layout.html. So I think it's better to have a `/deep/` version of bootstrap.