# Polymer designer - IE and Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, polymer, web-component

I have been looking at creating a new polymer designer based on http://www.polymer-project.org/tools/designer/

One thing that surprises me is the inconsistencies between browser in regards to the properties and styles panel. Obviously everything works well in Chrome but in IE and Firefox things get a bit screwed up.

Chrome

[image]

IE

[image]

This looks like a 1em difference but I am struggling how to make this consistent between browsers.

The situation is even worse for the styles panel between chrome, IE and Firefow

Chrome

[image]

IE

[image]

Firefox

[image]

The question: Are these inconsistencies application specific or a result of the shadow dom polyfill or some other polyfill being used?

Is there some guidance on how to address these issues?

Being a business app it is most likely to be used in IE :-( and if it is app specific I can just take greater care when constructing my app.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not seeing those issues on FF 31 on Win 8.1 using the latest build of designer. I am seeing the IE 11 issues though. Would you mind filing a bug and including the screenshots: https://github.com/polymer/designer/issues

Comment: possible duplicate of [Polymer custom element styles with HTML imports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818788/polymer-custom-element-styles-with-html-imports)

Comment: The last time I looked, this has all been fixed. Thanks Polymer Team